# Divide operation yields different result with the last decimal digit in Python, than that of a regular calc

Tags: python-3.x, math, decimal, division

I am trying to perform a divide operation in python,
`(3000/365)*365`
which prints 3000.0000000000005. Whereas in actual this should return 3000?

Can someone help me understand what am I missing here?

Comment: result for `(3000/365)*3000` should be `24657.534246575346`

Comment: My bad a typo, apologies it is (3000/365)*365

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: As pointed out by others, what you're seeing is the result of floating point arithmetic. You might also be interested in exact decimal arithmetic. I think there are probably implementations of that for Python; a web search should find some resouces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programming languages has floting point precesion errors. which cause sometime this kind of issues.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, it is because of the precision when using floating points.

A solution would be to round the result:

```
(round(3000/365*365,2)
```

and if you don't want a float, you could use int

```
int((round(3000/365*365,2))
```

Not sure if there is another approach, but hope this helps.